# Scroll UITableView and keep cell values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have this code that creates cells for my UITableView and puts a textField in each cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215, (cell.contentView.bounds.size.height-30)/2, 60, 30)];

    [myTextField setDelegate: self];
    myTextField.tag = indexPath.section;
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)myTextField.tag);


    myTextField.placeholder = @"0%";
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [cell addSubview:myTextField];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.cellLabels[indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}
```

The cell labels are retrieved from an array so even when the user scrolls the table view the cells labels remain the same, however I find that when the tableview is scrolled and a cell is out of view, when it returns its text is cleared and replaced by the placeholder text. Considering the fact that the textfield texts are based on user input, how do I fix this so the inputs remain when the textfield is recreated on return to screen.

More details: In the app, on the previous page the user chooses the number of items they want displayed and the name(cellLabel) of each item. For example 2 apples and 2 oranges. Each item is a section in the tableView so when the code is called you get a list with "apples" in the first two cells and "oranges" in the next two. All 4 cells has a textfield next to it.

Comment: What happens if you dont set any placeholder text on the textfield ? Have you tried that yet ?

Comment: They still get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. When the user types something into a text field, you remember what they typed (maybe you put the string into an array or something) - research how to get the text on change separately. Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, get the text from the array or whatever, and put it into the text field.
2. If you'll only ever have a few cells, then you can create them all a-priori, put them somewhere (like an array, again), and the in cellForRowAtIndexPath, get the right one.

Comment: In theory this makes sense, but because cellForRowAtIndexPath is continually called each time a cell leaves the screen and returns, the textfield will be recreated and ultimately this might not work out.

Comment: Will try and report back

Comment: You don't have to create the cell in cellForRow, you can do anything you want (include get the existing cell from an array).